# Как подружить mongodb и connect-history-api-fallback для совместной работы

Tags: mongodb, express, spa, vue-router

SPA на vue mode: 'history' + сервер на express хочу подключить mongo, но без connect-history-api-fallback роуты на сервере работают некорректно, а с ним не работают запросы к бд, по отдельности все работает, есть ли обходные пути, от чего отказатся, возможно нужны другие настройки для корректной работы SPA?